Sphinxプロジェクトフォルダを任意の階層に配置する方法
やりたいこと
開発プロジェクトにおいて、複数のドキュメントを作成し、それぞれsphinxドキュメントプロジェクトで管理したいです。
困っていること
ドキュメントフォルダを階層化すると、Pythonソースのモジュールドキュメントが生成できなくなります。
原因が分かりません。
試したこと
pythonソースコード
./source/init.py　：　空ファイル
./source/app.py
def main(a:int,b:int) -> int:
    """ main

    Args:
        a (int): a
        b (int): b

    Returns:
        int: add a+b
    """    
    return a+b

ans = main(1,2)

print(ans)

1.一階層のみのドキュメント生成
参考動画：【業務自動化】PythonのDocstirngからドキュメントを自動生成！〜Sphinxを使ってみよう〜
参考動画をもとにプロジェクトの一階層目./docsには、ドキュメントを生成することができました。
installしたパッケージ
esbonio
sphinx
sphinx-autobuild

Sphinxプロジェクトの生成
sphinx-apidoc -F -H study_sphinx -A t.funahashi -V 0.1 -o .\docs\ .\source\

./docsフォルダ以下の構成
./docs
│  conf.py
│  index.rst
│  make.bat
│  Makefile
│  source.rst
│
├─_build
├─_static
└─_templates

Edit conf.py
./docs/conf.py

from pathlib import Path
import os
import sys

project_dir = str(Path(__file__).parent.parent)
source_dir = project_dir + "\source"
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(source_dir))
...

extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'sphinx.ext.todo',
    'sphinx.ext.napoleon',
]
...

language = 'ja'


...
html_theme = 'bizstyle'

Build Sphinx
sphinx-build -b html .\docs\ .\docs\_build\

結果

2.二階層のドキュメント生成
以下のフォルダにドキュメントプロジェクトを生成します。
./docs/develop
この構成にすると、Pythonソースコードからモジュールドキュメントが生成されません。
sphinx-apidoc -F -H study_sphinx -A t.funahashi -V 0.1 -o .\docs\develop\ .\source\

./docs/develop
│  conf.py
│  index.rst
│  make.bat
│  Makefile
│  source.rst
│
├─develop
│  │  conf.py
│  │  index.rst
│  │  make.bat
│  │  Makefile
│  │  source.rst
│  │
│  ├─_build
│  ├─_static
│  └─_templates

Edit conf.py
./docs/conf.py

from pathlib import Path
import os
import sys

project_dir = str(Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent)
source_dir = project_dir + "\source"
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(source_dir))
...

extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'sphinx.ext.todo',
    'sphinx.ext.napoleon',
]
...

language = 'ja'


...
html_theme = 'bizstyle'

結果


手元で試してみましたが、 ./docs/ を指定しても、 ./docs/develop/ を指定しても、同じようにファイルが生成されているようです。
$ sphinx-apidoc --version
sphinx-apidoc 7.1.2

./docs/ を指定した場合
$ sphinx-apidoc -F -H study_sphinx -A whoami -V 0.1 -o ./docs/ ./source/
Creating file ./docs/conftest.rst.
Creating file ./docs/manage.rst.
Creating file ./docs/account.rst.
Creating file ./docs/account.management.rst.
Creating file ./docs/account.management.commands.rst.
Creating file ./docs/account.migrations.rst.
Creating file ./docs/account.tests.rst.
...

./docs/develop/ を指定した場合
$ sphinx-apidoc -F -H study_sphinx -A whoami -V 0.1 -o ./docs/develop/ ./source/
Creating file ./docs/develop/conftest.rst.
Creating file ./docs/develop/manage.rst.
Creating file ./docs/develop/account.rst.
Creating file ./docs/develop/account.management.rst.
Creating file ./docs/develop/account.management.commands.rst.
Creating file ./docs/develop/account.migrations.rst.
Creating file ./docs/develop/account.tests.rst.
...

そのため恐らく conf.py の sys.path の設定でなにかズレているのかもしれません。
ズレていると、以下の様にビルド時にWARNINGが表示されました。
$ sphinx-build -b html ./docs/develop/ _build
Running Sphinx v7.1.2
making output directory... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
writing output... 
building [html]: targets for 128 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [new config] 128 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] some.tests
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'admin' from module 'account'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'account'
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import ...

この場合、以下の様に指定することでもパスが設定できます。
$ PYTHONPATH=./source/ sphinx-build -b html ./docs/develop/ _build

いずれにしても、うまく行かない場合は、sphinx-apidocやsphinx-buildのログになにか警告が出ていのではないかと思います。
